# Change Github commit's name

Tags: git, github, commit

I was wondering if there was a way to change a Github commit's name, even if it isn't my last commit and it was made 18 hour ago.
Stating that I am new to this, is it possible?

Comment: Does this hlep you? https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-and-editing-commits/changing-a-commit-message

Comment: I don't know hot to navigate to the repository that contains the commit I want to amend.

Comment: Commits are a Git thing, not a GitHub thing. Therefore, you want to change the author of a commit with Git.